# Lambda body reduction in Lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm studying lambda calculus with De Bruijn indexes, and have these functions.

$$
zero := (\lambda\lambda.1)\\
succ := (\lambda\lambda\lambda.2 (3 2) 1)
$$

Now I want an algorithm to reduce $succ\ zero$

$$
\beta\ succ\ zero \\
\beta\ (\lambda\lambda\lambda.2 (3 2) 1)\ (\lambda\lambda.1)\\
\beta\ \lambda\lambda.2 ((\lambda\lambda.1) 2) 1
$$

where $\beta$ is the beta reduction function.

I tried to come up with an algorithm but it stops here because the head of the expression is not an application it wouldn't go further. I will continue the reduction that I like to implement

$$
\beta\ \lambda\lambda.2 ((\lambda\lambda.1) 2) 1\\
\beta\ \lambda\lambda.2 (\lambda.1) 1\\
\beta\ \lambda\lambda.2 1\\
$$

The problem that I'm facing is that in my program the application is a data type with two parameters `App term term` and this term $2 (\lambda.1) 1$ corresponds to this in code `App (App 2 (Lamb 1 1)) 1)`. By recursing on this structure I will never match the term $(\lambda.1) 1$ and will never be able to reduce it

I need this to compare numbers, for example

$$
one := (\lambda\lambda.2 1) \\
one' := \beta\ (succ\ zero)
$$

If I want $one$ to be syntactically equal to $one'$ I need to be able to normalize the function body, any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

My definition of `succ` is wrong, the correct is $\lambda\lambda\lambda.2 (3 2 1)$ not $\lambda\lambda\lambda.2 (3 2) 1$

Answer (score 1):

The [PL Zoo](http://plzoo.andrej.com/) has a programming language [lambda](http://plzoo.andrej.com/language/lambda.html) which uses de Bruijn indices (see the type [`term`](https://github.com/andrejbauer/plzoo/blob/master/src/lambda/syntax.ml#L3)) and explicit substitutions (described [here](http://math.andrej.com/2012/11/29/how-to-implement-dependent-type-theory-iii/)) to implement reduction, see [norm](https://github.com/andrejbauer/plzoo/blob/master/src/lambda/norm.ml#L13), which actually implements four different strategies, depending on what flags it is given.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the Dot constructor denoting? I saw that you used explicit substitutions, what are the pros and cons of having explicit substitutions?

Comment: Ohh ok is in the blog post, thanks!!!